# Kotlin Cross-platform mobile vs Flutter

Tags: flutter, kotlin

Flutter is work out of box. Write code on Dart and it's work on Android and iOS. Nice.

But what about Kotlin Cross-platform mobile ? Is it work out of box? And where I can find simple tutorial for Kotlin Cross-platform mobile?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Using Kotlin Cross-platform you can share business logic between platforms. UI has to be written natively.

A little overview here:

https://www.jetbrains.com/lp/mobilecrossplatform/

Comment: Can I use Kotlin Cross-platform in production code?

Comment: @a_subscriber kotlin multiplatform https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/evolution/components-stability.html is in Additions in Incremental Releases (AIR) state, which means things can deprecate but will removed after a notice unlike breaking of sources. It might not be production ready.